# Protractor - Dynamically build input for "element" function

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I am new to Protractor and I am trying to write a function that will accept 2 values and has to return the element like this

```
  this.getinput = function(x, y) {
     var text123 = "by." + x + "('"  + y + "')"
     return element(text123);
```

So x and y here can be any values like

```
   x: "buttonText" y:"save"
   x: "class"      y: ".css"
```

This works

```
     element(by.buttonText('save'))
```

but if I try to send the same through the variables as in the function, it fails as "Invalid element locator". Is there a nicer way to get this done dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup a object to mapping `by` API as following:

```
var byMap = {
    buttontext: by.buttonText,
    css: by.css,
    xpath: by.xpath,
    id: by.id,
    tagname: by.tagName,
    name: by.name,
    linktext: by.linkText,
};

function buildLocator(using, value) {
    return byMap[using.toLowerCase()](value);
}

function getInput(using, value) {
    return element(buildLocator(using, value));
}
```